# URL not found on server when uploading Laravel project

Tags: laravel, apache, centos7

I have a Laravel project that is on a live server and I have made a copy to place in a development server. When I try to login, it says `The requested URL /xxxx/login was not found on this server.`.
I am not quite sure what to do, as I changed my `httpd.conf` to

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

but I am still getting the same error after restarting apache. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't config for the virtual host or you config it wrong.

You can find that config file under folder `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts/` Below are a sample file config:

```
$ cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts/yoursife.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName    yourdomain.com
    ServerAdmin   youradmin_server_mail
    DocumentRoot /your_src_path/public/
    <Directory "/your_src_path/public/" >
        Options FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog  /your_src_path/public/logs/error_log
    CustomLog /your_src_path/public/logs/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

You can create a new file if you want.

Comment: I do not see a `vhosts` file in my `conf.d` folder. Should I make a new one?

Comment: Yes. You can try make a new one and after that you have to restart graceful your server to make it done. The restart graceful command is depend on your httpd service, so you can google more but you can try `apachectl -k graceful` after you config your virtual host file.